# HTML download link prompting "No File Selected"

Tags: html, apache, jsp, tomcat

I'm trying to create a download link but when the button is clicked, a dialog box with error "No File Selected" is prompted. I suspect there is something wrong in the file location defined. Below is my code. Thanks in advance!

```
<form method="get" action="info.txt">
<button type="submit">INFO</button>
</form>
```

The file location : 
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\webapps\foo\info.txt

Comment: Please provide a full path in action.

Comment: action="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\webapps\foo\info.txt"                       Tried it. Still the same error.